# Change Azure Master Database Collation ARM Template

Tags: database, sql, settings, azure-sql, azure-arm-template

I'm deploying an environment in Azure using **ARM Templates**. I'm using Azure SQL Server and 4 databases. I went to restore a bacpac file and got an error complaining about **different collation settings** between my master database and the database my team is working on.

Is it possible to set the master database collation to be **SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS** and not **SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS** (note the CI vs. CS)? The database we're using has to be SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS and we want the master to match it as well.

Answer (score 0):

A few pointers. [This article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/set-or-change-the-database-collation?view=sql-server-2017) talks about changing collation for the database. [This article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/master-database?view=sql-server-2017) talks about master db and specifically mentions that its collation is equal to the server collation.  Looking at the rest api to [create Azure SQL server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/servers/createorupdate) - its not possible to define collation at creation time >> not possible to change it.

But looking at [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/164538/can-i-create-a-azure-sql-server-server-with-a-different-collation) you shouldn't need to.